# Project Euler # 17 in Ruby, my (wrong) answer makes logical sense to me

Tags: ruby

I've stared my code for over an hour now, going through each method again and again. However, this very wrong code looks correct to me and I don't know which part has a mistake. Any insight you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.

Problem:

If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?

```
@ones = [3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4]
@teens = [6, 6, 8, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8] #without "ten"
@tens = [6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6] #also without "ten"
@hundred = 7
@hundred_and = 10
@one_thousand = 11

def sum_array(array)
  array.inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
end

def one_to_nineteen
  sum_array(@ones) + sum_array(@teens) + 3 #ten
end

def sum_tens
  sum = 0
  @tens.each { |x| sum += sum_array(@ones) + (x * 10) } #0-9
  return sum
end

def one_to_ninety_nine
  return one_to_nineteen + sum_tens
end

def sum_hundreds
  sum = 0
  @ones.each do |x|
    sum += (x + @hundred) + ((x + @hundred_and) * one_to_ninety_nine) + one_to_ninety_nine
  end
  return sum
end

def one_to_one_thousand
  print one_to_ninety_nine + sum_hundreds + @one_thousand
end

one_to_one_thousand
```

This outputs: 117750, which (after looking up the answer online) is quite wrong.

Comment: For reference, what is the desired output? Have you (using your method) written a program for the numbers 1-10 and tested it? And moved up to 1-100 then 1-1000 etc. Might help.

Comment: I just tried to do this and I also messed up, although I yielded 15752...

Comment: The desired output is : 21124

And I tested the method for 1-10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st problem is that `@teens` is wrong. How did you compute it?

Coding it like this makes it harder to make such a slip.

```
@teens = 'eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen
          seventeen eighteen nineteen'.split.map(&:size)
```

The 2nd problem is that `@tens` is also wrong, so instead use

```
@tens = 'twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety'.split.map(&:size)
```

Now you should find `one_to_ninety_nine` returns `854` which is correct.

The 3rd problem is

```
sum += (x + @hundred) + ((x + @hundred_and) * one_to_ninety_nine) + one_to_ninety_nine
```

It should be

```
sum += (x + @hundred) + ((x + @hundred_and) * 99) + one_to_ninety_nine
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first construct the following hash:

```
words =
    { ones: [(1..9).to_a,
               %w| one two three four five six seven eight nine |],
      teens: [(0..9).to_a,
               %w| ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen | +
               %w| sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen |],
      tens:  [(2..9).to_a,
               %w| twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety |]
    }
  #=> {:ones =>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  #             ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]],
  #    :teens=>[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  #             ["ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
  #              "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]],
  #    :tens =>[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  #             ["twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]]}
```

Next I would convert `words` to a hash `counts` that has the same keys, but with values that are hashes with keys equal to possible digit values and values equals to the sizes of the corresponding words:

```
counts = words.each_with_object({}) { |(k,(nbrs, vals)),h|
  h[k] = Hash[nbrs.zip(vals.map(&:size))] }
counts[:ones][0] = 0
counts
  #=> {:ones =>{1=>3, 2=>3, 3=>5, 4=>4, 5=>4, 6=>3, 7=>5, 8=>5, 9=>4, 0=>0},
  #    :teens=>{0=>3, 1=>6, 2=>6, 3=>8, 4=>8, 5=>7, 6=>7, 7=>9, 8=>8, 9=>8},
  #    :tens =>{2=>6, 3=>6, 4=>5, 5=>5, 6=>5, 7=>7, 8=>6, 9=>6}}
```

We can now sum words sizes for each number between `1` and `1000`:

```
HUNDRED = "hundred".size
  #=> 7
AND     = "and".size
  #=> 3

(1..999).reduce("onethousand".size) do |tot, i|
  hun, rest = i.divmod(100)
  ten, one = rest.divmod(10)
  hun_count =
  case hun
  when 0 then 0
  else counts[:ones][hun] + HUNDRED + ((i % 100 == 0) ? 0 : AND)
  end     
  ten_count =
  case ten
  when 0
    counts[:ones][one]
  when 1  
    counts[:teens][one]
  else
    counts[:tens][ten] + counts[:ones][one]
  end
  tot + hun_count + ten_count
end
  #=> 21124
```